# in vba, can I safely delete buttons and sheets that are associated with the macro that is running? (out of memory, unreadable content errors)

Tags: vba, excel

I do not see any immediate errors or problems when I have a macro delete a button (or sheet with a button on it) that is the same button that was used to start the same macro initially. To be 100% accurate, it is really a sub called within the sub associated with a the button that is actually deleting said button.

However, I am trying to solve intermittent 'out of memory' and 'unreadable content' errors and disappearing button issues (all in same workbook) with very little success and I am wondering if what I am doing (described above) in vba is some how silently causing these issues later.

EDIT: I do get a warning immediately when I delete the 'associated button when in break mode, but it only indicates that I can't use break mode after deleting the button. However, that makes me suspicious.

All buttons are ActiveX, but they were Controls.

The workbook is large, but the issue is intermittent, so I don't think that is the issue.

EDIT: I have already controlled for 'too much stuff open' (not enough memory).

This is how I delete the buttons:

```
Dim Shp As Shape
For Each Shp In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas").Shapes
 Shp.Delete
Next Shp
```

This is how I delete the sheet with the button on it:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas").Delete
```

Please note that the question is asking about a macro 'self-deleting' its own associated button, but I am okay with hearing more about 'out of memory' and 'unreadable content' errors and disappearing button issues generally.

I have 15 years experience with Excel and VBA, but no formal CS education, so please free to dive in deep with your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are completely done using and referring to the buttons themselves, I don't see how deleting them would create any problems.  With the linear nature of VBA, once that button is pressed and the SubRoutine is called, the button would no longer have any ties to the macro (again, as long as there is no other code that in some way points to or refers to the button).